# Mysql Query Substring?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database of TV shows and ratings, and I want to do this:
Search for all the ratings of certain TV Shows that are from a certain network...

I have the ratings table with the ID of the Show, but it doesn't have a column for the ID of the network... And I have a table for the TV shows, in which I have the ID of the network for each one.

How can I do that? Is this a case of substring??

My tables structure:

Networks table:

```
id
name
```

TV Shows table:

```
id
name
network_id
```

Ratings table:

```
id
tv_show_id
season
episode
rating
```

And what I want to do is:

```
SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE (network_id = X)
```

(but the Ratings table doesn't have a network_id column)

Thanks!

Comment: Your table structure.  Please show it.

Comment: @Daedalus: Networks table: id, name / TV Shows table: id, name, network_id / Ratings table: id, season, episode, tvshow_id, rating / I want to get all the ratings from network X... I solved this by creating a column 'network_id' in my ratings table.. but I think this isn't the better solution... I don't know.

Comment: Post it in your question, not in a comment.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. This is my first question... Why did people vote it down?? I searched A LOT before I asked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to join your shows table with your ratings table, you probably need something like this:

```
SELECT ratings.*
FROM shows INNER JOIN ratings
     ON shows.id = ratings.show_id
WHERE
  shows.netword_id = 1
```

Please see this link to see how [INNER JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx) works.